# How can I get the random samples from a very large collection in Python efficiently

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to sample numbers which can be used as the annual income for a particular dataset.
I have the following code which explodes in memory and the system hangs

`np.random.choice(xrange(750000, 1000000000), size=254)`

Then I changed the code to 
`np.random.choice(xrange(75, 100000), size=254) * 10000`

the code works fine with less memory but.
I am really not sure if affects the sampling from the distribution.

Can I do it any efficient manner.

Comment: Why are you using python 2?

Comment: Does python3 provide any advantage over python2

Comment: Use `np.random.randint(750000,1000000000,size=254)`?